# nuget pack fails to recreate a package

Tags: nuget

I have a simple nuget package that I am creating. When I create it using "nuget pack", it works and creates the .nupkg file, but when I rerun the same command I get this error:

```
The process cannot access the file '<my .nupkg file>' because it is being used by another process.
```

But - no one is using this file (I checked through Process Explorer, and also I am able to simply delete it). When I delete this file and run the command again - it succeeds.

I didn't find anything useful googling for this, maybe someone here knows what to do?

Comment: It starting to look like a nuget.exe bug - I filed a ticket with more details in their site - https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root cause found: Since the base path and output path were the same - the nuget opened the existing package (even though I excluded it using "-Exclude"), giving this error. Using a separate output path solves this issue.